# Extra records are being added everytime the form is refreshed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

the code that I am using to insert product information via php into mysql is this.

```
<?php include 'dbconnect.php'; ?>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
    <input type="text" name="product_name"/>
    <input type="text" name="product_price" />

        <select name="product_cat">
        <?php
        $results = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY cat_name");
            while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
            extract($row);
            echo "<option value='"."{$cat_id}"."'>"."{$cat_name}"."</option>";
            }  
        $results->free();
        ?>
        </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php   
    if($_POST){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO products (prd_name, prd_price) VALUES(?,?)";
    if($stmt = $connect->prepare($sql) )
        {
            $productname = $_POST['product_name'];
            $productprice = $_POST['product_price'];
            $categoryid = $_POST['product_cat'];
            $stmt->bind_param("si", $productname, $productprice);
        if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $lastid = $stmt->insert_id;
                $productsku = "PR".$productlastid;

                $insert_row = $connect->query("INSERT INTO categoryproducts (CategoryId, productId) VALUES ($categoryid, $lastid)");
                $insert_row = $connect->query("UPDATE products SET productSku = '".$productsku."' WHERE productId =".$productlastid."");

                echo "Created";
                $stmt->close();
            }else{
                    die("Unable to create category.");
                }
                }else{
                die("Unable to prepare statement.");
            }
                $connect->close();
            }
        ?>    

</body>
</html>
```

The code works fine and as I would want it to but every time after the record are saved and I refresh the form there is an additional record which is created in the table categoryproducts. My best guess is that the problem is somewhere here after the statement is executed

```
if($stmt->execute())
        {
            $lastid = $stmt->insert_id;
            $productsku = "PR".$productlastid;

            $insert_row = $connect->query("INSERT INTO categoryproducts (CategoryId, productId) VALUES ($categoryid, $lastid)");
            $insert_row = $connect->query("UPDATE products SET productSku = '".$productsku."' WHERE productId =".$productlastid."");

            echo "Created";
            $stmt->close();
        }else{
                die("Unable to create category.");
            }
            }else{
            die("Unable to prepare statement.");
        }
            $connect->close();
        }
```

I guess I need to close a connection somewhere after the form is submitted. Can anyone help?

Comment: When you say "form is refreshed" are you saying that you are doing it manually? Like pressing F5 on your browser ?

Comment: So there is your problem. On HTML after you submit a form and you press F5 the last action you did was submit all the information to the server, in your case, you are saying to your browser to send everything again to be processed so as you are not checking if that product isn't already on the database it get inserted again. If you press F5 again and again it will insert one new registry every time you do it. So, check if the product isn't already on your database or search on google: how to avoid double insert on refresh. I'm leaving now, so don't have time to make an answer to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `if($_POST){` use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` with a header redirect to the same page or to another page of your choice.

I.e.: and using [`ob_start();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) which will prevent getting
`Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...`

```
<?php 
ob_start();
?>

<?php include 'dbconnect.php'; ?>

// ... 

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO products (prd_name, prd_price) VALUES(?,?)";
    if($stmt = $connect->prepare($sql) )
        {
            $productname = $_POST['product_name'];
            $productprice = $_POST['product_price'];
            $categoryid = $_POST['product_cat'];
            $stmt->bind_param("si", $productname, $productprice);
        if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $lastid = $stmt->insert_id;
                $productsku = "PR".$productlastid;

                $insert_row = $connect->query("INSERT INTO categoryproducts (CategoryId, productId) VALUES ($categoryid, $lastid)");
                $insert_row = $connect->query("UPDATE products SET productSku = '".$productsku."' WHERE productId =".$productlastid."");

                // echo "Created";

                $stmt->close();

                header("Location: this_page.php");
                exit;

            }else{
                    die("Unable to create category.");
                }
                }else{
                die("Unable to prepare statement.");
            }
                $connect->close();
            } // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))
?>
```

You could also look into using [**Ajax**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), or use two different files, one for your form and the other for the PHP/SQL with a header redirection.

Comment: thank you for suggesting. Sounds good, Ill do what you asked and see if that helps

Comment: added header location as suggested but not ob_start(), why do you want me to add ob_start(), can you please explain.

Comment: @ManishB It could throw an error for headers already sent. `ob_start();` helps to not have that error. Did it work though?